# Error in defaultCluster(cl) : no cluster 'cl' supplied and none is registered

Tags: r

Sorry if I ask format or ask this properly, I am new to R and Stackoverflow. I have an issue with the default clusters, but I genuinely don't know what that is. I am trying to generate sample designs, but I keep running into a code error.

```
Error in defaultCluster(cl) : 
no cluster 'cl' supplied and none is registered
```

But I got it to work with my previous file. but I couldn't get it to work with this one.

```
att2=read.dbf("Final_CORT_Northeast")
head(att2)


seed<-sample(1000000,1)
set.seed(seed)


Stratdsgn<-list("Wetland"=list(panel=c(PanelOne=200),
                               seltype="Equal"),
                "Town"=list(panel=c(PanelOne=50),
                            seltype="Equal"),
                "Road"=list(panel=c(PanelOne=250),
                            seltype="Equal"))

str(att2)
Stratsites <-grts(design=Stratdsgn,
                  DesignID = "Equaldesign",
                  type.frame="finite",
                  src.frame="shapefile",
                  in.shape = "Final_CORT_Northeast",
                  att.frame=att2,
                  stratum = "Type",
                  shapefile = TRUE,
                  prj="Final_CORT_Northeast",
                  out.shape = "Final_North_500Site")
```

Again sorry if I didn't input this properly. I'd appreciate any help someone could provide on what an error in default cluster (cl) is.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Kiefer, welcome to StackOverflow! We could use a little more information to help you diagnose the problem. Cluster errors often occur when using parallel processing, but we need to know where these functions are coming from in order to diagnose those problems. Can you assemble a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us?

Comment: Hi Dubukay, Is it possible to upload all of my data? I've gotten it to work before on another shapefile, so I don't know if I'd get the error if I made an example.

Comment: It's probably not necessary to upload *all* your data, but parallel processing issues are tricky. Some people share links to Google Drive folders, but most people find it simpler to reduce the data down to the smallest possible subset that still causes issues. Is it possible to subset the shapefile in some way that only the part causing the error needs to be uploaded, ideally as an R object? It'll definitely help to fill in information about which packages you're using and that may help us diagnose as well.

Comment: Here is my google drive folder for the code I have. I am working with the spsurvey package. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qmy2uyKgYslykyhSrMFRi6aNVekDjIbA?usp=sharing

Comment: Odd. I'm not even able to open the .dbf file after downloading because read.dbf insists on appending .shp to the filename, after which it can't find the file. Are you using the latest version of spsurvey (4.1.0)?

Comment: I am not sure, I will look at that. I assume installing the package on R doesn't always mean I am in the most up to date version? or are you saying that this may have worked for an older version of the package and no longer does with the updated version?

Comment: Well, this issue was that my shapefile was made of polygons, not points. The finite command didn't have anything to hold on to. Once centroids were entered into the shapefile polygons the parameters were met and R was happy.